# How could I make my website display a tree structure in search engine results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, google-search

I want to make my website be able to show a tree structure of links when a user searches it through Google.

I've used sitemap to generate the structure:

```
# Set the host name for URL creation
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "https://lazyair.co"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add '/about-us', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/contact_us', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/tutorial', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/user', :changefreq => 'daily'
end
```

## Expected  format

[image]

## Current  format

[image]

Comment: The "duplicate" isn't really high quality, but this question _is_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about SEO and not programming.

Answer (score 1):

There is no foolproof way to create [Google Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en), however you can structure your navigation to encourage them:

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however, to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

And presumably you have to have enough traffic for the algorithm to evaluate the utility of the links.